# Not receiving “x-razorpay-signature” header in the request made by razorpay webhook on callback URL

Tags: node.js, nestjs, razorpay

Any idea why am I not receiving `x-razorpay-signature` header in the request made by razorpay webhook on callback URL?
I am receiving the signature on frontend but not on backend(node) in the request header.

**Note:**
I am using `ngrok` for proxy because razorpay does not allow private ip for webhooks and I am testing this locally on my machine.

[image]

Comment: Judging from the X-Forwarded-* headers, there seems to be a reverse proxy (for loadbalancing or possibly SSL termination) between your app & the web. Sometimes you have to configure it to forward certain headers to your (Node) backend. More info about your set-up would help others to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @RickN I've updated my question. Please review it and let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

I did not set secret while creating razorpay webhooks and that is why I was not receiving any signature. Once I updated it, it started working.